# Memory fills up in foreach loop

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, out-of-memory

I'm having some memory issues with a foreach loop.

I have a large array, filled with objects, which I want to loop through (it's used to export data into an excel sheet).

When I loop through the array with a foreach loop, I get an 'out of memory' error. When I echo memory_get_usage() each 100 iterations, I can see the memory filling up.

When I change the foreach-loop in a for-loop, the memory usage stays consistently low. Why?

At the the end of both loops I unset the $object (and $objects[$key]). I can see the __destruct() method on each specific object gets fired at the end of each iteration (after i unset the object). Still the memory doesn't seem to free up in a foreach loop.

So my question is, why does the memory fill up in the foreach loop? And is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you loading putting the value in another variable? Please show your code so we can help you figure out what is happening.